# Ansible ec2_vpc_igw VPC does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm working on a playbook to deploy a VPC with an internet gateway. For some reason, the Ansible module is unable to find the gateway. The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_vpc_igw_module.html) on this module is sparse, and the example is incomplete.

Ansible bits:

```
- name: Create default VPC
  ec2_vpc_net:
    name: acme_baseline
    cidr_block: 10.11.0.0/16
    region: us-east-1
    state: present
    tags:
      Owner: "someuser"
  register: baseline_vpc

- name: Create internet gateway
  ec2_vpc_igw:
    vpc_id: "{{ baseline_vpc.vpc.id }}"
    region: us-east-1
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "acme_baseline"
      Owner: "someuser"
  register: baseline_igw
```

Direct AWS CLI has no issues finding the VPC:

```
# aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids vpc-0123546897 --region us-east-1
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "IsDefault": false,
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "acme_baseline",
                    "Key": "Name"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "someuser",
                    "Key": "Owner"
                }
            ],
            "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
                {
                    "CidrBlock": "10.11.0.0/16",
                    "CidrBlockState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    },
                    "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-00001444444"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0123546897",
            "CidrBlock": "10.11.0.0/16",
            "State": "available",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-aaaaaaa",
            "OwnerId": "000000000000",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output of the two Ansible blocks (verbose mode x3):

```
ansible-playbook 2.7.9
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

TASK [aws-baseline : Create default VPC] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/foo/roles/aws-baseline/tasks/main.yml:26
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz `" && echo ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_vpc_net.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-14593RSX_GI/tmpMcth9v TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_net.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_net.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_net.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "cidr_block": [
                "10.11.0.0/16"
            ],
            "dhcp_opts_id": null,
            "dns_hostnames": true,
            "dns_support": true,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "multi_ok": false,
            "name": "acme_baseline",
            "profile": null,
            "purge_cidrs": false,
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "security_token": null,
            "state": "present",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "acme_baseline",
                "Owner": "someuser"
            },
            "tenancy": "default",
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "vpc": {
        "cidr_block": "10.11.0.0/16",
        "cidr_block_association_set": [
            {
                "association_id": "vpc-cidr-assoc-00001444444",
                "cidr_block": "10.11.0.0/16",
                "cidr_block_state": {
                    "state": "associated"
                }
            }
        ],
        "classic_link_enabled": false,
        "dhcp_options_id": "dopt-aaaaaaa",
        "id": "vpc-0123546897",
        "instance_tenancy": "default",
        "is_default": false,
        "owner_id": "000000000000",
        "state": "available",
        "tags": {
            "Name": "acme_baseline",
            "Owner": "someuser"
        }
    }
}

TASK [aws-baseline : Create internet gateway] **********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/foo/roles/aws-baseline/tasks/main.yml:37
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `" && echo ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_vpc_igw.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-14593RSX_GI/tmp1Ttirp TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_igw.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_igw.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/AnsiballZ_ec2_vpc_igw.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_igw_payload_o6xIsP/__main__.py", line 244, in main
    result = ensure_igw_present(connection, vpc_id, tags, check_mode=module.check_mode)
  File "/tmp/ansible_ec2_vpc_igw_payload_o6xIsP/__main__.py", line 184, in ensure_igw_present
    'Unable to create Internet Gateway, error: {0}'.format(e))

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "profile": null,
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "security_token": null,
            "state": "present",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "acme_baseline",
                "Owner": "someuser"
            },
            "validate_certs": true,
            "vpc_id": "vpc-0123546897"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Unable to create Internet Gateway, error: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidVpcID.NotFound</Code><Message>The vpc ID 'vpc-0123546897' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>111111111-22222222-33333</RequestID></Response>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code, and it worked for me (Ansible 2.7.10)

Judging by the error, you were a victim of eventual consistency on the AWS side.

The solution would be to wait a bit between each step.

However, I strongly advise *not* to use Ansible for this. Use any infrastructure-as-code tool for the bare-bones infra provisioning in AWS. Tools like CloudFormation, Terraform, or the new CDK from AWS (still in development).

I speak from personal experience. You want the core cloud infra to be deployed with IaC, and more dynamic things (instances, etc) with some other configuration management tool like Ansible.

Comment: Having done it both ways, I concur.  Unfortunately, that decision is often by the customer, who is, of course, always right.

Comment: I've found that just having a `debug` call to show the registered variable can alleviate the problem.

Comment: Even with your workaround, you are still subject to the whims of eventual consistency. You should probably do retries 60 / delay 1 in the task that depend on previously created resources.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Ansible 2.7.10 to see if that was why it worked for [Kaurin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213137/kaurin). I still had the same issue unfortunately. I did stumble across a bug however.

In my scenario, I'm using credentials stored in ~/.aws/credentials. I have several profiles setup, and I use sts-assume-role to jump between child accounts. This works without issue for all of the Ansible AWS modules up to this point, but the ec2_vpc_igw module doesn't recognize this. It provisions the Internet Gateway (IGW) in the source account, not the child account. Once the IGW is deployed, it's unable to associate it with the VPC identified as it's not in the child account.

I'm going to submit a bug report with the maintainers.

Update- this is [already documented](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50757).
Bottom line- this Ansible module uses boto, not boto3. As such, it doesn't respect profiles that work with other modules.